# Undeclared identifier TEncoding delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, undeclared-identifier

Hi i want to use TEncoding to convert Tbytes to utf7  but when i use TEncoding
delphi gives following error.

Undeclared identifier: 'TEncoding'

i am using delphi 7.

what to do??

Comment: TEncoding not present in d7. Tell us what your real problem is. UTF7 sounds unlikely.

Comment: i am reading a exe in C# and transferring it to delphi application and want to write data to a file. but some encoding problem is there.

Comment: I don't know what reading an exe in C# means.

Comment: Oh there IS something called UTF7. Reversed my own edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TEncoding` was introduced in Delphi 2009. You should upgrade to a newer version of Delphi, such as XE.

Comment: any other alternative in delphi 7 to convert to utf7.

Comment: Yes, but it is inconvenient. By the way, are you sure that you really want UTF7 and not UTF8?

Comment: i am reading a exe in C# and transferring it to delphi application so its Windows-1252

Comment: Ask about that in a new question, Vinamra. It's certainly possible to convert byte buffers to a UTF-7 encoding, but the comments for *this* question are not the appropriate place to discuss it. This question is specifically about TEncoding, not UTF-7 conversions.

Comment: C# does not use UTF7 does it?

Answer (score 8):

The `SysUtils.TEncoding` class is not available in D7.  Use the Win32 API `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` functions instead, specifying `CP_UTF7` as the codepage.

Comment: This one is correct Vinamra. Either fix your question, delete it, or accept this answer.  I still think you're confused and you want UTF8, not UTF7.